# How can I execute a script in specific dir with subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, call

When I need to execute a script-B from script-A, I am using subprocess call to start that script-B in a specific directory-B, but it executes as though it is in the directory-A of the script-A which is calling it with subprocess.

Script-B creates files. The files that it creates should be created in directory-B, but they are generated in directory-A instead.

Below: PATH is directory-B, self is script-B.

I am trying

```
PATH = some_directory
# Get current script name

self = os.path.basename(__file__)
    
# Copy old-self to desired directory.
os.popen(f"copy {self} {PATH}\\{self}")

# Open new-self in selected dir
subprocess.call([f"{PATH}\{self}"])
```

Comment: (1) `shutil.copy(file,PATH)` will do the copy.  No external needed.  (2) `cwd = os.getcwd()` / `os.chdir(PATH)` / `subprocess...` / `os.chdir(cwd)`.  (3) Just do `subprocess.call([self])`.  No string work needed.

Comment: Your answer was very broad, but I figured it out after some time.  I changed some stuff about how the script-b is initialized, code is altered but it is overall the same as my original.

I got it to work using: 
    subprocess.call(["f"{PATH}\\script.bat""],cwd=PATH)

Comment: That shouldn't work.  If you are in the `PATH` directory, then there is not going to be a file called `"PATH\script.bat"`.  It would be `"./script.bat"`.

Comment: The code snippet doesn't use envi PATH variable; as in this case PATH = input() and the input is data received from a socket connection, although I didn't explicitly state that, I simply used dummy value of some_directory -- due that the question was only concerning subprocess executing an application within a separate directory, and not executing as if in the directory of the application calling subprocess. Perhaps, anyway it is malpractice to use PATH in this way and I should use something else like DesiredDir or path, instead. Thank you, though, for directing me toward the solution.

Comment: I know this.  What I'm saying is, if you create a directory called "aaa", then create a file called "aaa/script.bat", then do "chdir aaa", the command "aaa\script.bat" will fail -- the file is not found.